# CakePHP: MySQL Query in Route

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

I don't know the first thing about doing queries in CakePHP OR doing routes in CakePHP so I don't even know how to start to find a solution for my question. Maybe you can help.

I want users to be able to go to:

```
http://www.domain.com/movies/1
```

OR

```
http://www.domain.com/movie-nickname
```

Both would access the "pages" controller, "view" action. And they should both come up with the page id = 1.

(I don't want them to simply go to http://www.domain.com/pages/1)

Each page has a nickname for the URL, but if left blank the url will be http://www.domain.com/CATEGORY/PAGE as shown in the first example.

If the nickname is not left blank, is there a way I can do a query inside my route that says "SELECT id FROM pages WHERE nickname = 'nickname'"

On top of this, if the nickname in the pages table is "this that", the URL should be http://www.domain.com/this-that, meaning the hyphen needs to be replaced with spaces and THEN execute the query.

I have the route for the first URL which is:

```
Router::connect(
    '/:category/:page',
    array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'),
    array(
        'pass' => array('page'),
        'page' => '[0-9]+',
        'category' => 'shows|music|games|books|hobbies'
    )
);
```

Is the second option I am looking for possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my custom routing.

```
App::uses('ClassRegistry', 'Utility');

// HOMEPAGE
Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'index', 'action' => 'index'));

$requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptName = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

for($i= 0;$i < sizeof($scriptName);$i++)
        {
      if ($requestURI[$i]     == $scriptName[$i])
              {
                unset($requestURI[$i]);
            }
      }

$param = array_values($requestURI);

$param1 = $param[0]; // domain.com/page-nickname
$param2 = $param[1]; // domain.com/category_id/page_id

// convert 'page-nickname' to 'page nickname' which is what it would be in db
$pagelink = str_replace('-', ' ', $param1);

// initiate Page mode;
$pagesModel = ClassRegistry::init('Page');

// check if there is a matching page in the db that has link column like 'page nickname'
$matchedpage = $pagesModel->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('Page.link LIKE' => "$pagelink"), 'recursive' => '0'
));


// Cache::write('routepagelinks', $pagelinks);

// if there is a match
if($matchedpage['Page']['id']){
    Router::connect('/' . $param1, array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view', 'page' => $matchedpage['Page']['id']), array(
    'pass' => array('page'),
    'page' => '[0-9]+'
    ));

// ... more custom routing if there is a match

}

// general routing info here


// if no page-nickname, routes page for domain.com/category_id/page_id
Router::connect(
'/:category/:page',
array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'view'),
array(
    'pass' => array('page'),
    'page' => '[0-9]+',
    'category' => 'shows|music|games|books|hobbies'
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

While it may be possible, you don't often see the router performing such logic. More often, the router passes this through to the controller and the controller handles dissecting the URL path.

As proof, consider how the native *edit* routes work. The router doesn't test the database for an existing *id*. The controller does.